# Having trouble accessing a list value inside a map | C++

Tags: c++

I've made a map that has string keys with either string values or list values. It gives me no syntax errors and has worked fine for me so far until I've tried accessing the list value. I've tried setting it as a variable, using auto, and no go. Don't know what else to try, any help is appreciated.

```
using map = std::map<std::string, std::variant<std::string, std::list<std::string>>>; 
std::list<std::string> TagList{ "Paid", "Needs invoice" }; 


 map m{ {"TIME",TimeHourAndMin}, {"HEADER","Title"},{"TAGS", TagList},{"CONTENT", "Hey this is content!"} };

// E0135 class "std::variant<std::string, std::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>>" has no member "begin"   
// E0135 class "std::variant<std::string, std::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>>" has no member "end"
for (auto it = m["TAGS"].begin(); it != m["TAGS"].end(); it++) {


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `m["TAGS"]` is of type `std::variant` and so doesn't have a `begin` method. Since you want to get the list out of your variant you can use the `std::get` function to do that

```
auto it = std::get<std::list<std::string>>(m["TAGS"]).begin();
```